# signal of $\frac{1}{f}$ Noise

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density

I am working on kind of signals that can be classified as 1/f Noise.
In this [article](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/40.php) is explained that the time history of 1/f noise follows a power law proportional to $t^{-\alpha}$. I am very surprised about this, because when I think to this kind of signal histories, they do not seems to me proportional to $t^{-\alpha}$ or a series of $t^{-\alpha}$.
Have someone an explanation for this?

I have also read this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235741759_Bak_P_Tang_C_Wiesenfeld_K_Self-organized_criticality_An_explanation_of_1f_noise_Phys_Rev_Lett_59_381-384), that highlights the proportionality to $t^{-\alpha}$ and introduces the theory of the "Self-Organized criticality". But I didn't find an explanation to my problem.

Comment: uff that article is quite something – it confuses  the power spectral density of noise with the fourier transform of a deterministic signal. Generally, whenever an article claims to write about a basic mathematical phenomen that the call a  "mystery that has resisted explanation for over 80 years", I'd be slightly doubtful. Nothing about an 1/f PSD is especially hard to understand. The article is worded to impress, not to be mathematically close to correct, to be honest.

Comment: @MarcusMuller I have read the article and it does not seem to confuse PSD with FT. It states that the PSD of the pink noise is $\omega^{-1}$ and its magnitude spectrum  is $\omega^{-1/2}$, which is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Power-law behaviors in frequency can be found in several unrelated observations and systems. This is apparently the case for $1/f$ or flicker noise. Note that an exact $\alpha=1$ exponent might be too stringent, and people can be interested in a wider range, like  $1/f^\alpha$ with $1/2\le\alpha\le3/2$.

[image: Images of white, pink and Brown noises with spectral densities]

The plot above is from [1/f noise](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/1/f_noise).
Since only looking at the decay of a PSD does not provide you with much ideas about the morphology of signals, you might be interested in looking at generative processes, or accumulated actions that may generate such types of spectra, from physics phenomena (superposition of relaxation processes, infinitely large fluctuations, noise in diffusion processes etc.). **And then maybe find analogies when the phenomenon you are studying**.
Here are three papers of interest:

- [$1/f$  noise: a pedagogical review](https://arxiv.org/ftp/physics/papers/0204/0204033.pdf) by Edoardo Milotti
- [$1/f$ noise’’ in music: Music from $1/f$ noise](https://doi.org/10.1121/1.381721) by Richard F. Voss and John Clarke

> The spectral density of fluctuations in the audio power of many
> musical selections and of English speech varies approximately as $1/f$
> (f is the frequency) down to a frequency of 5×10−4 Hz. This result
> implies that the audio‐power fluctuations are correlated over all
> times in the same manner as ’’$1/f$ noise’’ in electronic components.
> The frequency fluctuations of music also have a $1/f$ spectral density
> at frequencies down to the inverse of the length of the piece of
> music. The frequency fluctuations of English speech have a quite
> different behavior, with a single characteristic time of about 0.1 s,
> the average length of a syllable. The observations on music suggest
> that $1/f$ noise is a good choice for stochastic composition.
> Compositions in which the frequency and duration of each note were
> determined by $1/f$ noise sources sounded pleasing. Those generated by
> white-noise sources sounded too random, while those generated by
> $1/f^2$ noise sounded too correlated.

- [Power laws, Pareto distributions and Zipf's law](https://doi.org/10.1080/00107510500052444)

Comment: You could be interested by [Power laws, Pareto distributions and Zipf's law](https://doi.org/10.1080/00107510500052444) too

Comment: (+1) This is simply a delightful and enlightening answer! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, let me come back with some hints, because I am not able to offer a satisfactory solution at the present time

Comment: If a continuous signal follows a one-sided power-law, then  its Fourier possesses a power-law behavior (in some theoretical sense). But (AFAIK) **one cannot make it work  the other way around**: if you observe a power-law on the PSD of a discrete time signal, and even more if you only observe it "approximately" (uncertainty on the slope) and on a reduced bandwidth (always the case in practice), there is absolutely no guarantee  that the time signal follows a power-law decay.  Because the low-frequency components (away from the power-law), the unknown phase etc. disallow such conclusions

Answer (score 2):

> time history of 1/f noise follows a power law proportional to t−α

If "time history" is supposed to mean "time domain waveform" that sentence is just non-sense.

1/f noise is just pink noise. There are many ways to generate it but in most cases it's a steady state signal with a flat envelope and it can be as long or as short as you want it to be. Nothing of it looks like $u(t)\cdot t^{-\alpha}$ . End of story.

We've been over this in your previous questions: the power spectral density alone doesn't describe your time domain signal. The shape of that signal is determined by the phase of the spectrum as well.

The relationship does not even match the autocorrelation of pink noise. The autocorrelation is indeed the inverse Fourier transform of the PSD, but the PSD is real valued and the Fourier transform of $u(t)\cdot t^{-\alpha}$ is complex.

To summarize: you have found an interesting Fourier Transform pair but it doesn't apply in any way form or shape to pink noise (or 1/f noise).

Comment: Exactly. The linked article really confuses "fourier transform of autocorrelation" and "time-domain signal", and states multiple mathematical fallacies. There's really not much to salvage there.

Comment: @MardyOwens you literally cannot make a definite statement on the time domain of noise from the PSD – the PSD is the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function (which needs to exist to begin with), which is the *expected value of the conjugate product of a realization at any two time points with a fixed time delta*. Unless I'm very much missing something here, you can end up with an *expected* time-delta dependency that is $u(\tau)\tau^{-\alpha}$ without ever seeing a random signal that has that shape itself in each individual realization; that's the thing about random signals!

Comment: I'm starting to repeat myself, but what you calculate when you calculate the inverse fourier transform of a PSD is the autocorrelation function, which is an expectation of a conjugate product. It doesn't give you the time-domain function!

Comment: Now, Laurent is right, this function is a bit special, because a product that's a declining exponential is made from such terms itself, but that doesn't change the fact this is still *in expectation only*! There's nothing wrong with Laurent's answer, but your interpretation is a bit off.

Comment: It is – in expectation. You could for example have a source of noise that spits out "white 0-mean noise" half of the times you look at it, and the other times spits out something proportional to $t^{-1/6}$. In expectation, the functions produced by that system are still proportional to $t^{-1/6}$, but that by no means any particular realization is

Comment: I'll try again: You have discovered and interesting Fourier Transform pair. However: it's NOT applicable to pink noise, and it's also NOT applicable to the autocorrelation of pink noise. It's NOT applicable to pink noise at all and I have a hard time coming up with a real world signal where this would be useful. I'm afraid the article that you cited misapplies that relationship,

Comment: Even disregarding the "expectation" aspect: You don't have the spectrum, you only have the magnitude of the spectrum. In order to make $t^{-1/6}$ appear you need to add a rather bizarre phase function to that magnitude. That choice is not justified by anything you have said. Any other choice of phase function would result in a completely different time signal that has nothing to do $t^{-1/6}$. Most likely your signal phase is uniformly distributed on $[-\pi,\pi]$ as is the case for most noise like signals. For the autocorrelation, phase must be 0

Comment: But why listen to us? Why don't you take a look at your actual signal and see if you can find anything related to  $t^{-1/6}$ in there?

Comment: @MardyOwens as Laurent himself told you now, you're still making the wrong assumption that the time-domain signal and the noise spectrum are linked through the Fourier transform. They're not. You really have to give up that notion – it's plain wrong.

Comment: "I just cannot understand why starting from a signal proportional to $t{−1/6}$ is the only way to explain the slope of the FT," It's not the only way. There are many other ways to explain the slope and they are far more likely than $t{−1/6}$